# Carbon: compare diffForHumans

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, dateinterval

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and Carbon library.

I'm trying to compare multiple `diffForHumans` results.

For example I have three differences:

`3 weeks after`

`7 days after`

`2 days after`

Is it possible to compare these to find minimum, maximum and average value?

In this example that would be:

- min: 2 days
- max: 3 weeks
- avg: 10 days

I could use `diff` instead of `diffForHumans` if necessary (and it seems to me it's going to be to get precise results for average).

Any pointers on what too Google are appreciated since I can't find anything on this topic so I hope I'm searching for the wrong thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from `diffForHumans` is, well, for humans and humans are, as we know, terrible calculators. Don't do it.

Given an array of `\Carbon`, you can compute your values as follows:

```
$carbons = [ ... ];
$diffs   = array_map(function ($c) { return $c->diffInSeconds(); }, $carbons);
$max = $carbons[array_search(max($diffs), $diffs)];
$min = $carbons[array_search(min($diffs), $diffs)];
$avg = array_sum($diffs)/count($diffs);
```

If you insist, and want to sort the output from `diffForHumans`, you can key off of the modifier and the numeric value. Once ordered, you can shift the min and pop the max:

```
function score($c) {
    $scores = [ 1 => 'second', 'minute', 'hour', 'day', 'week', 'month', 'year' ];
    $diff = $c->diffForHumans();
    foreach ($scores as $multiplier => $word) {
        if (false !== strpos($diff, $word)) {
            return $multiplier * (int)$diff;
        }
    }
    return (int)$diff;
}
usort(
    $carbons,
    function ($a, $b) { return score($a) <=> score($b); }
);
```

Bear in mind that `diffForHumans` output can be short form (eg, `'d'` instead of `'day'`), as well as translated into another language. So you have to be careful manipulating its output.

*Note: the code above has only been mentally compiled.*

Comment: So basicaly, use `diffInSeconds` and compare those (integers I suppose) ? So simple and I can't see a practical flaw, awesome. You wouldn't believe the workarounds I tried to implement... I'll try it tomorrow but it should probably work so thanks! And one rhetoric question: why isn't something similar to this implemented into Carbon?

Comment: I imagine Carbon lacks this ability because Carbon is, fundamentally, about an *instance of time*, whereas the operations you want are about a *collection of instances of time*.